php array_filter issues, trying to get data out, but its not working
I'm pretty new to PHP and I'm trying to figure out the array_filter, and why its not seeming to work for me.
I've got a large array from the namecheap sandbox to test and learn with from a colleague of mine.
So i'm passing the array and a specified domain TLD into my function, and i'm expecting a single Price to be returned from the 'register' product category.
class registerPrice {
    function getRegisterPrice($domainTLD, $newArr) {
        // Extract the "Register" product category for the target TLD
        $registerCategory = array_filter($newArr['CommandResponse']['UserGetPricingResult']['ProductType'], function ($category) use ($domainTLD) {
            return $category['@attributes']['Name'] === 'register' && $category['Product']['@attributes']['Name'] === $domainTLD;
        });

        // Extract the prices for the 1-year duration from the "register" category for the target TLD
        $registerPrices = array_column($registerCategory, 'Product');
        $registerPriceForOneYear = null;
        foreach ($registerPrices as $product) {
            foreach ($product as $price) {
                if ($price['@attributes']['Duration'] == 1 && $price['@attributes']['DurationType'] == 'YEAR') {
                    $registerPriceForOneYear = $price['Price']['@attributes']['Price'];
                    break 2; // Exit both loops once the price for 1 year is found
                }
            }
        }
        return $registerPriceForOneYear;
    }   
}

Part of the array I'm using:
Array
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [Status] => OK
        )

    [Errors] => Array
        (
        )

    [Warnings] => Array
        (
        )

    [RequestedCommand] => namecheap.users.getpricing
    [CommandResponse] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [Type] => namecheap.users.getPricing
                )

            [UserGetPricingResult] => Array
                (
                    [ProductType] => Array
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [Name] => domains
                                )

                            [ProductCategory] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [Name] => reactivate
                                                )

                                            [Product] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [Name] => com
                                                        )

                                                    [Price] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [Duration] => 1
                                                                    [DurationType] => YEAR
                                                                    [Price] => 13.48
                                                                    [PricingType] => MULTIPLE
                                                                    [AdditionalCost] => 0.18
                                                                    [RegularPrice] => 15.88
                                                                    [RegularPriceType] => MULTIPLE
                                                                    [RegularAdditionalCost] => 0.18
                                                                    [RegularAdditionalCostType] => MULTIPLE
                                                                    [YourPrice] => 13.48
                                                                    [YourPriceType] => MULTIPLE
                                                                    [YourAdditonalCost] => 0.18
                                                                    [YourAdditonalCostType] => MULTIPLE
                                                                    [PromotionPrice] => 0.0
                                                                    [Currency] => USD
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [Name] => register
                                                )

                                            [Product] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [Name] => com
                                                        )

                                                    [Price] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [Duration] => 1
                                                                            [DurationType] => YEAR
                                                                            [Price] => 10.28
                                                                            [PricingType] => ABSOLUTE
                                                                            [AdditionalCost] => 0.18
                                                                            [RegularPrice] => 13.98
                                                                            [RegularPriceType] => MULTIPLE
                                                                            [RegularAdditionalCost] => 0.18
                                                                            [RegularAdditionalCostType] => MULTIPLE
                                                                            [YourPrice] => 10.28
                                                                            [YourPriceType] => ABSOLUTE
                                                                            [YourAdditonalCost] => 0.18
                                                                            [YourAdditonalCostType] => MULTIPLE
                                                                            [PromotionPrice] => 0.0
                                                                            [Currency] => USD
                                                                        )

                                                                )


I keep Getting the undefined array key error whenever I run this.
I know the data definitely exists because I can "hard code" it like this:
$domainRegistration = $newArr['CommandResponse']['UserGetPricingResult']['ProductType']['ProductCategory']['2']['Product']['Price']['0']['@attributes']['Price'];

The full error is here:
PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "@attributes" in D:\xampp\htdocs\sm\registrationPrice.php on line 6

Warning: Undefined array key "@attributes" in D:\xampp\htdocs\sm\registrationPrice.php on line 6

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in D:\xampp\htdocs\sm\registrationPrice.php on line 6

Warning: Undefined array key "@attributes" in D:\xampp\htdocs\sm\registrationPrice.php on line 6

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in D:\xampp\htdocs\sm\registrationPrice.php on line 6

line 6 is:
return $category['@attributes']['Name'] === 'register' && $category['Product']['@attributes']['Name'] === $domainTLD;

For the first parameter of array_filter(), you forgot ['ProductCategory'] at the end.

Hi, Thanks, yes i did.
I've tried so many times that I've introduced more errors.
From what I've seen it If I add the [productCategory] back in, I get my original issue back, which is that it seems to not be able to find the data and set it into the variable.
Any idea why it seems to be returning an empty array when the data is there for it to match?

please post array in json format  so that we can run test on it .

Here is a pastebin with the entire json encoded xml:
https://pastebin.com/ZxHJei6i

The filter needs to be over $newArr['CommandResponse']['UserGetPricingResult']['ProductType']['ProductCategory'].
The inner foreach loop needs to be over $product['Price'], not $product.
function getRegisterPrice($domainTLD, $newArr) {
    // Extract the "Register" product category for the target TLD
    $registerCategory = array_filter($newArr['CommandResponse']['UserGetPricingResult']['ProductType']['ProductCategory'], function ($category) use ($domainTLD) {
        //var_dump($category);
        $catName = $category['@attributes']['Name'];
        $prodName = $category['Product']['@attributes']['Name'];
        //echo "Cat: $catName\nProduct: $prodName\n";
        return $catName === 'register' && $prodName === $domainTLD;
    });
    //var_dump($registerCategory);
    // Extract the prices for the 1-year duration from the "register" category for the target TLD
    $registerPrices = array_column($registerCategory, 'Product');
    var_dump($registerPrices);
    $registerPriceForOneYear = null;
    foreach ($registerPrices as $product) {
        foreach ($product['Price'] as $price) {
            if ($price['@attributes']['Duration'] == 1 && $price['@attributes']['DurationType'] == 'YEAR') {
                $registerPriceForOneYear = $price['@attributes']['Price'];
                break 2; // Exit both loops once the price for 1 year is found
            }
        }
    }
    return $registerPriceForOneYear;
}

DEMO
